# CSS animation bug in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, animation, safari, webkit

I have a CSS animation with a delay and I pause it during the delay.
It works as expected on Firefox and Chrome, the "Hello" does not move.
However on Safari, the animation jumps to the last frame.
Why and how to fix please?

```js
function test() {
  var timeout = 1000;
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('animation').style.animationPlayState = 'paused';
  }, timeout);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", test);
```

```css
#animation {
  animation: test 2s linear 2s;
}

@keyframes test {
  to {
    transform: translateY(100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="animation">
  Hello (this text should not move)
</div>
```

If I remove the 2s delay, set the duration to 4s, and add a keyframe with transform:none, I can make this simple example work. However my real case has multiple animations that are synchronized with delays.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. In Safari 11.0 (macOS) it works as expected.

Comment: @Styx I just tested in Safari 11.0 and the bug still happens. The "Hello" jumps to the bottom instead of being paused.

Comment: Try this jsfiddle, please: https://jsfiddle.net/iStyx/2uqf1p9y/

Comment: The timeout must be set to 1000 to reproduce the bug.

Comment: So it will pause animation before it even started?

Comment: Yes it's what I want to do. (In my real app there are several animations.)

Comment: I gave it a try but am stumped as well. You could use `animation: none` to prevent the animation from starting but I guess that would defeat the purpose of pausing and running the animation.

Comment: I've played a lot with this thing, but it seems there is no workaround about this :(

Answer (score 12):

The Safari behaviour is only buggy when timeout is set to a value smaller than the animation delay. So, **a workaround is to set the initial state to `paused` via `animation-play-state`** and then control it via JS, as shown below:

```js
function test() {
  let el = document.getElementById("animation");
  let timeout = 1000;
  
  // Get the delay. No luck with el.style.animationDelay
  let delay =
    window
      .getComputedStyle(el)
      .getPropertyValue("animation-delay")
      .slice(0, -1) * 1000;

  // Only resume and later pause when timeout is greater than animation delay
  if (timeout > delay) {
    el.style.animationPlayState = "running";
    setTimeout(function() {
      el.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
    }, timeout);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", test);
```

```css
#animation {
  animation: test 2s linear 3s;
  animation-play-state: paused; /* Pause it right after you set it */
}

@keyframes test {
  to {
    transform: translateY(100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="animation">
  Hello (this text should not move)
</div>
```

Try different timeout values to see it working. Can't say why this is happening though. Looks like a bug to me. Tested on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 / Safari 11.0 (11604.1.38.1.7).

[**Codepen demo**](https://codepen.io/ksiabani/pen/gGdEYE)

Comment: Thanks. I've also come to the conclusion that it's a bug, especially since I've found other bugs. Safari seems incredibly buggy with animations. I guess I have to rework everything in Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer to the problem. However, if you remove the animation delay, pausing and restarting the animation works as it should. It seems then the animation delay is what is causing the problem. Perhaps rather than relying on css to handle the delay, programmatically control animation delay with javascript.

See below pausing and running the animation

```js
function test() {
  var timeout = 1000;
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('animation').style.animationPlayState ='paused';
    document.getElementById('animation').style.webkitAnimationPlayState ='paused';
  }, timeout);
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('animation').style.animationPlayState='running';
    document.getElementById('animation').style.webkitAnimationPlayState ='running';
  }, timeout * 2);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", test);
```

```css
#animation {
    -webkit-animation: test 2s linear;
        animation: test 2s linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes test {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
        transform: translateY(100px);
  }
}

@keyframes test {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
        transform: translateY(100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="animation">
  Hello (this text should not move)
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I noticed that. I found another workaround, I removed the delays and added keyframes and different animations.

Comment: Also I noticed that your code does not work as expected on mobile Safari 9.0. The text moves back and forward.

Comment: Yeah, there is definitely some bugginess as it comes to animation-play-state and safari.